# Custom CellRender da JList

Tags: java, layout, gui

Gostaria de fazer uma cell render com `JPanel` de maneira que ficassem da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria composto por uma `JPanel`, outra `JPanel` dentro que teria o background alterado e duas `JTextField` ou `JLabel`

Tentei entender como funciona o `CellRender` mas ninguém explica direito

```
public class CustomContactCellRender extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Object>{

    private static Contact_Info cinfo;
    JLabel name;
    JLabel msg;

    public CustomContactCellRender() {

        setOpaque(true);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this , BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel overallPanel = new JPanel();
        overallPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(overallPanel , BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        overallPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,400));
        add(overallPanel);

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
        firstPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        overallPanel.add(firstPanel);

        JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
        statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(37,37));
        statusPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        firstPanel.add(statusPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(3,40)) , BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(3,40)) , BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(40,3)) , BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(40,3)) , BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel photoPanel = new JPanel();
        photoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32,32));
        photoPanel.setLayout(null);
        statusPanel.add(photoPanel);

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel , BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        overallPanel.add(secondPanel);

        secondPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(3,this.getWidth())));

        name = new JLabel();
        name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,15));
        secondPanel.add(name);

        secondPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(4,this.getWidth())));

        msg = new JLabel();
        msg.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(),15));
        secondPanel.add(msg);

        secondPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(4,this.getWidth())));
    };

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        cinfo = Contact_Info.getInstance();

        name.setText(cinfo.getFirst_name(1));

        return this;
    }
```

#### EDIT: Código atualizado

Aonde fica o design da cell? em `CustomContactCellRender()` ou em `getListCellRendererComponent`?

Se alguém tiver uma dica também aceito

#### EDIT 2

creio eu que esteja certo... como setaria os nomes e adicionaria na `JList`?

Comment: Olá Lucas, se ninguém se habilitar primeiro amanhã eu escrevo uma resposta completa. Dito isso, veja que existe um exemplo de `ListCellRenderer` [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) (sendo aplicado a uma `ComboBox`, mas isso não importa). Você pode colocar lógica tanto no construtor (`CustomContactCellRender`) quanto no método que recupera o componente (`getListCellRendererComponent`).

Comment: O construtor é o melhor lugar para colocar lógica fixa, i.e. que não variam conforme o valor (e.g., o layout do painel); já o método deve fazer o resto (e.g., setar a imagem a ser exibida conforme o item atual; desenhar uma borda caso a célula esteja em foco, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas, tornando meus comentários uma resposta conforme prometido.

Sim você está no caminho certo. Existe um material sobre `ListCellRender` [no tutorial oficial do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). Você pode encontrar o código fonte do exemplo [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/CustomComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/CustomComboBoxDemo.java) (ele customiza um `JComboBox`, mas não existe muita diferença da prática).

### Sobre onde colocar cada coisa:

1. `CustomContactCellRender()` é o construtor do *renderer*, você pode colocar tudo o que for fixo aqui; o layout do seu painel, seus componentes e tudo mais que for relevante.
2. `getListCellRendererComponent`é o método que vai devolver o componente para cada item. Ajustes finos e exibição de valores do modelo devem todos serem feitos nesse método, pois somente nele você terá acesso ao objeto da lista (`value`), posição do elemento (`index`), etc.

### Sobre como setar o nome

Lembre-se sempre da separação entre *model* e *renderer*. O que alimenta a lista com valores é o `ListModel` (se você iniciou o combo com um array ou `Vector` o java construiu um *model* anônimo que herda de [AbstractListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) para você).

Pois bem, se você tem um `ListModel` de objetos do tipo `Contact`, os valores do `Renderer` também devem lidar com `Contact` (você pode especificar o tipo na declaração: `implements ListCellRenderer<Contact>`).

Uma vez feito isso a única coisa que o *renderer* deve fazer é alimentar seu componente com os valores recebidos:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Contact value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    name.setText(value.getNome());
    msg.setText(value.getMensagem()); 

    return this;
}
```

É claro que em uma aplicação real você deve também ter algum indicativo visual de foco e seleção; por exemplo, mudar a cor do *background* ou desenhar uma borda):

```
if (isSelected) {
    setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
    setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
} else {
    setBackground(list.getBackground());
    setForeground(list.getForeground());
}

if (cellHasFocus) {
   setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
} else
   setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
}
```

Para ajustar esse tipo de detalhe é bom dar uma olhada no código fonte da classe [DefaultListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) (isso varia bastante conforme a versão do JDK).

O conjunto trabalhando junto:

```
Contact[] myContacts = new Contact[] {
    new Contact("Hans Solo", "Do not call him Harrison Ford"),
    new Contact("Jabba the Hutt", "Not Pizza Hut")
};
JList<Contact> list = new JList<>(myContacts);
list.setCellRenderer(new CustomContactCellRender());
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Teria algum meio de contato? caso tenha mais alguma duvida?

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar. Eu geralmente estou de olho aqui no site. No meu perfil você encontra meu blog (e também não é muito difícil de me encontrar em outras redes ;).

Comment: mandei uma menssagem face com um erro que esta retornando

Comment: Olá Lucas, não recebi. Não quer criar uma nova pergunta aqui no SOpt? Abraços

Comment: @Antony Accioly
http://pastebin.com/aTLyUi5S
essa é a classe CustomCell teria como dar uma checada?

Comment: Olá Lucas, tudo bem? A primeira vista não encontrei nada errado com o seu código (fora a ausência de código para tratar items selecionados e focus). Você não quer abrir uma pergunta apontando o erro que está recebendo e o problema que está tendo? Abraços